# Minimize the length of number to fixed length

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to minimize the length of number to fixed value 3 with decimal point 1

Ex: 
After calculation value of @a=45689.45.

Now I need to get value of @a =45.6 
If the value is less then 100 i.e if it is 89.63 then I don't need to change it.

At last value of @a should be decimal of (3,1)

Comment: @a cannot be both decimal(3,1) and 89.63 (it would be 89.6)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
case when @a >= 100 then
    round(@a / power(10, floor(log10(@a)) - 1), 1, 1)
else @a
end
```

Comment: Needs a cast to decimal(3,1) to get 45.6 instead of 45.60000000

Comment: Should the CASE expression not use >= (greater than or equal)?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos good point but I think the OP is ambiguous so would need to add the cast depending on their needs (E.g. they want 89.63 as an output which can't be represented by decimal(3,1))

Comment: 89.63 is less than 100 so it shouldn't be modified

Comment: Aye but it also cant be *"At last value of @a should be decimal of (3,1)"*

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @a DECIMAL(7, 2)=45689.45

SELECT CASE
         WHEN len(CONVERT(INT, @a)) > 3 THEN LEFT(@a / CONVERT(INT, '1' + replicate(0, len(CONVERT(INT, @a))-2)), 4)
         ELSE @a
       END
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this to death but without using string manipulation this might do the job;

```
declare @i decimal(18, 6); set @i = 2000

select cast(round(@i / case when @i >= 100 then (power(10, floor(log10(@i)) - 1)) else 1.0 end, 1) as decimal(3,1)
```

Fingers crossed :)

Rhys

Comment: That's similar to Alex's answer but instead of truncating it rounds. This will produce 45.70000..

Comment: You still need to truncate using ROUND(...,1,**1**) instead of rounding with ROUND(...,1). The third argument specifies either rounding (default 0) or truncation (any non-zero value)